# is there any method to view uploaded file in output directry

Tags: php

hi  in my project we uploads a file and it will save in uploadfolder but i want to my uploads in my pc f folders so i creacte the my programm now my file is saving in that folder but it not displaying in my page

"alt="User profile picture">

Comment: How are you *trying* to display the image in your page and how is it *failing*?

Answer (score 0):

Before displaying first check file is available in the folder.
You can  use function like

```
if(file_exists('path/filename'))
{
  // Your code
}
Or 
if(is_file('path/file_name'))
{
  // Your code
}
```

Comment: if (file_exists($output_dir. $_FILES["myfile"]["name"]))
  {
      unlink($output_dir. $_FILES["myfile"]["name"]);
  }

Comment: Is your file save in folder?  can you display the code

Comment: if (isset($_POST['profile_upload'])){
    $output_dir = UPLOADS."/profile/";